# create basic object with $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have been all over the tutorial sites and couldn't get this working

I'm trying to make an angular app that works over the REST with my server(I downloaded [this](https://github.com/githubjeka/angular-yii2) and managed to get it working but I started a new one from scratch to understand everything better). making the REST server was the easy part since I'm a php guy, but I'm not so familiar with angular part.

I made a simple directory with `yeoman` and put my REST server next to it in another folder, so I have :

- root
- ------app  with all angular code here
- ------engine  which is a yii2 framework

in `app/script/app.js` I have:

```
'use strict'; // BTW what is this line doing?

var app = angular
  .module('gardeshApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })

      .when('/post/index' , {
            templateUrl: 'views/post/index.html',
            controller : 'PostList'
        })

      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

I wanted make some kind of Model object to put received data in, so I created a Post model like :

```
app.factory('Post' , ['$resource'] , function($resource){
    var Post = $resource('http://localhost/testApp/engine/web/post/:id' , {id : '@id'} , {update: {method: 'PUT'}});

    angular.extend(Post.prototype , {

        save: function (values) {
            if (values) {
                angular.extend(this, values);
            }
            if (this.id) {
                return this.$update();
            }
            return this.$save();
        }

    });

});
```

and a controller to fetch the data:

```
app
    .controller('PostList', ['$scope', '$http' , '$resource',
    function($scope, $http) {

//     $http.get('http://localhost/testApp/engine/web/post').success(function(data){
//         console.log(data); // this works fine and gets the json ed data
//     });


        var posts = new Post();
        console.log(posts.query());

    }]);
```

I don't want to call `$http.get` myself, I want to make it dynamic but the Error says Post is not defined.

how can I make a proper Post Object to represent the model I'm fetching?

Comment: You haven't returned anything from your `Post` factory method. I think what you're intending is to return the result of `angular.extend(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like this:

```
app.factory('Post' , ['$resource'] , function($resource){
    var Post = $resource('http://localhost/testApp/engine/web/post/:id', 
        {
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        }
    );
    return Post;
});
```

And,

```
app.controller('PostList', ['$scope', '$http' , 'Post',
    function($scope, $http, Post) {
        console.log(Post.query());
    }]);
```

You need to return your built object in a factory in order to make it dependency-injectable later. Then in your controller, you need to declare that your want `Post`, and Angular will inject it for you.